# How to install RocksDB into ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, rocksdb

RocksDB is a key / value database created by facebook and works very well, but it lacks documentation on how to install the production version.

Answer (score 15):

The code below works fine on Ubuntu 16.04 and was placed here to help

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb.git
cd rocksdb

DEBUG_LEVEL=0 make shared_lib install-shared

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Hope this helps.

Kemper

Comment: In later versions you may need to `USE_RTTI=1` to get the functionality which relies on RTTI e.g. virtual functions from e.g. `WriteBatch::Handler`s.

Comment: > DEBUG_LEVEL=0 make shared_lib install-shared 

Do I put it in some flle or run in terminal?

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo apt-get install librocksdb-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

I was going through the same thing but I found answer, installation instructions are in fact there, just need to snoop around a little

https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/INSTALL.md

to wrap these instructions in few lines:

**Dependencies:**

```
sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev libsnappy-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libzstd-dev
```

**Installation:**

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb.git
cd rocksdb/
make all
```

Comment: what is the next?, it builds librocksdb.a, RocksDB static library, how to run it..

Comment: `rocksdb/INSTALL.md`: "**Important:** If you plan to run RocksDB in production, don't compile using default `make` or `make all`. That will compile RocksDB in debug mode, which is much slower than release mode."

Comment: I am also trying to know what to do after librocksdb.a has been created. Did anyone found the answer? I want to create a table in rocksdb, but not finding right steps to do that anywhere.

Comment: @user3339691 As I understand it, RocksDB is an embeddable key-value pair db, so we will have to write code to create a database and store data.