# Getting started with RocksDB in Ubuntu

Tags: rocksdb

I'm trying to start using RocksDB but i don't understand what i have to run once i have executed the compiling.

I have run the following

1 Dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev libsnappy-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libzstd-dev
```

2 Installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb.git
cd rocksdb/
make static_lib
```

I have executed the recommended
[How to install RocksDB into ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928827/how-to-install-rocksdb-into-ubuntu)
and here:
[image]

And now? how can i start it? how can i use it?

i read carefully the git page but I'm in front a folders full of file, and i don't know what to run...

https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Basic-Operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RocksDB is a library which means it needs another program to tell it what to do. See [examples](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/tree/main/examples) and how the Makefile builds those examples. C++ is the primary supported language but bindings exist for many other languages also.

There is [some command line support with ldb](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Administration-and-Data-Access-Tool#ldb-tool) (`make ldb`), but that is only intended for debugging and maintenance.

Comment: I would like to use it with Faust (https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust) this mean that i can even avoid to compile it and just install the library that i need with (pip install python-rocksdb). Is the first time that i came across something like this, so it is nowhere, In my mind i have SQL, so a DB installed some where, but instead is just a library that sit on top of an application. RocksDB is like a folder with files inside,  similar to saving data in JSON? Every app has his own DB embedded, Correct? Thanks!